# Yii Dynamic Dropdown - Expensive Query

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, yii

I have a Yii dropdown which loads a table of cities, states, zipcodes, lat and lon. When loading the state dropdown, it takes forever. Is there a way to speed up the query to cut down on pageload time? I've included my view:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'State', CHtml::listData(Zipcodes::model()->findAll(),
'State', 'State', 'State'), array('empty'=>'-- Choose State --'));
```

The table is 41,000 entries. Setting the $groupField in listData() didn't seem to give any noticeable improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CDbCriteria, I set the "GROUP BY" for the query:

```
$stateGroupBy = new CDbCriteria; // i got that bitch criteria. bitches love criteria!
$stateGroupBy->group = 'State'; // group by state
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'State', CHtml::listData(Zipcodes::model()->findAll($stateGroupBy), 'State', 'State'), 
        array('ajax' => 
            array(
                  'type'=>'POST', //request type
                  'url'=>CController::createUrl('search/dynamiccities'), #we don't have to use search/, we could just say dynamiccities
                  'update'=>'#Zipcodes_City',
                  /*'data'=>'js:jQuery(this).serialize()'*/
                  ),
            'empty'=>'-- Choose State --')
        );
```

I flaked out in getting back to this, but this cut down on the load significantly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can have two ways:

1) Use cache (with long or no expiration time, because this data you have are not dynamic).
First time your loading time will not change, but after that, it will bee much, much faster, because cache will be already saved.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#query-caching

```
$zipcodes = Zipcodes::model()->cache(3600*24*7)->findAll(); //cache for a week
```

- Using cache you need to edit your config/main.php file

> ```
> //...
> 'components' => array(
>     //...
>     'cache'=>array( 
>          'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache',
>          //'class'=>'system.caching.CDummyCache',
>          //other cache class
>     ),
>     //...
> ),
> //...
> ```

2) Maybe consider to try **CJuiAutoComplete**
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAutoComplete/
It will give you results only on typing and matching your interested data.

Answer (score 1):

Not loading 41k entries and placing them in HTML `<option>` tags seems to be a very good start... :-)

Only load those you need using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Is the state drop-down culling unique states from that table, i.e., you end up with 50-ish results? You might want to construct the query manually and see where the bottleneck is. For complex queries, this is often dramatically faster than using AR, which I'm assuming you are using to create the model. I'm also assuming you are *not* trying to load 41k records into a drop-down.

We might need a bit more detail about the structure of the table, how you are creating the model, etc.